# User Roles with Windows Authentication not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, model-view-controller, authorization

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC which uses Windows Authentication. I have 2 Active Directory Groups and I want to check if the user is in that group, this didn't work with my code, so I checked with User.IsInRole. It gives me strange results, in group 1, which I am not a member of anymore, it returns true. For group 2, which I am a member of, it returns false. For a colleague it returns false for both (he is in group 2).

Any ideas why that is the case?

Here is the code which I used to configure my ASP.NET Core app.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthorization(opt => {
                opt.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("DOMAIN\\GROUP 1"));
                opt.AddPolicy("Write", policy => policy.RequireRole("DOMAIN\\GROUP 2"));
});
```

Comment: Try to write a [custom Policy Authorization handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2#requirements) to check User's all ADGroups and check if they contains your desired group name. Refer: [Using AD groups to authorise access to pages using IIS Windows Authentication](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152453.aspx)

Comment: @ZhiLv I tried it and I got the same result as with my approach

Comment: If I check it with GroupPrincipal and UserPrincipal it returns the correct results.